# Hadoop set --config parameter via code

Tags: hadoop

In the Hadoop CLI, there is a --config parameter that I can set in order to overwrite the default configuration directory. I was wondering if there is some attribute in the Configuration object (or somewhere else) where I can specify this parameter in code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();          
configuration.addResource(new Path("/location/of/core-site.xml"));
configuration.addResource(new Path("/location/of/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

You can change configuration directly from CLI by providing -D parameter,:

```
hadoop jar jar.jar namespace.Class -D configuration.parameter=value
```

To make it work you have to implement ToolRunner interface. Do not worry it is quite easy, here is nice tutorial - [Implementing the Tool interface for MapReduce drive](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/hadoop-implementing-the-tool-interface-for-mapreduce-driver/)

Hope it helps